# Publically exposing a WCF service which is behind firewall

Tags: wcf, security, firewall

**Enviroment**

Consider the following production environment setup for a web application:

End user --Internet--> web server in DMZ --**Firewall**--> WCF hosted on app server --> DB Server

**Constraint:**

Also consider that we cannot change anything from the infrastructure point of view. For example, open ports, change any firewall setting etc.

**Problem:**

We want to expose the WCF, which is hosted on the app server, to external clients. We are trying to solve this as follows:

End user --Internet--> Router WCF in DMZ --**Firewall**--> WCF hosted on app server --> DB Server

Please note that we cannot establish a db connection from the DMZ environment where the WCF needs to be hosted so that the external clients can consume it. We have developed a "Router WCF" which passes through all messages to the internal WCF and vice-versa.

This solution adds an unnecessary overhead of serializing and de-serializing data. There must a better and proper way of doing this. We are looking forward to the community for guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Open a port of the firewall? or am I missing a requirement

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Mr. Saunders, I appreciate your enthusiasm to educate me. I never knew that it is one of the requirements (still I can't understand why) to "try" something before asking questions. It seems to contradict with "why to reinvent the wheel" saying. I thought that is what sites like stackoverflow are good at. "Share Knowledge". However, in this case, I have mentioned how we are thinking to solve this problem and want people to validate if my thinking is correct before I spend hours of effort doing something which is not right.

Answer (score 0):

In DMZ the bibliography tells you: always create an intermediate layer. This means another machine on the internet will be the point of connection and it will proxy the connection back to WCF.

The machine is the web server you seem to mention, that is stupid, has no data, and (to be a proper DMZ) has a firewall between it and all the machines (WCF and the others) it serves that permits only IP:PORTS used on such machines.

In this scenario, usually Apache on the public web server with a URL-rewrite rule (i.e if it is /x/y send it to servera.internal.com:9900 -  if it is /x/z send it to serverb.internal.com:9901 etc...) is enough, but there are plenty of solutions of course.

It seems you are doing exactly this, why do you say it is not the proper solution?

*DMZs could seem a bit dated as protection mechanism (I agree) but you have to think when servers like your WCF machine had dozens of ports opened, and you wanted to lower the risk of random ports on web-facing machines, a giant attack surface. Nowadays everything can work with  couple of ports opened, so it can seem "silly" to do all of this just to forward a TCP port. But it is still valuable as (for example) if servers behind the web server in DMZ do not have internet access, even when WCF is compromised, the attacker cannot use its own reverse shell to deploy what it is nowadays called an APT (yesterday backdoor). The attacker "won't see" his own machine from WCF as the DMZ provides the connection to the external world.*

Comment: I have edited my question, please see if it makes any sense to you now. Thank you for your help.